# Data loss with XHR requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to simulate bad internet connection when I'm sending data to server via XHR. If connection is bad and XHR request isn't completed in 2 seconds it's aborted using XHR.timeout. Weird thing occurred that sometimes even if XHR is aborted data gets to server after 1 minute. I wonder how it's that possible? If the connection is good and data gets to server and in meantime connection breaks, data would get to server in miliseconds not in minutes? Where could this data be stacked so it arrives to server after minutes?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify timeout option on AJAX request as

```
 $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        url: 'your_URL',
        data: valueToSUbmit,
        timeout: 20000,
        error: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {
        }
```

Comment: The timeout was set with timeout property(xhr.timeout) and it was working